# print unicode issue using curses in python

Tags: python, unicode, printing, python-curses

I'm writing a game using python with curses library. Somebody made a new version of curses for Windows, So I'm using this library. But I got a problem printing unicodes in terminal. And I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me.

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper


def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    stdscr.addstr(10, 10, '⭘', 8)

    stdscr.getch()
    stdscr.getch()

wrapper(main)
```

[printing half of the unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlxZA.png)
this terminal is printing half of the unicode.  I want to show entire uncode character, but I can't
Is this can be fixed? What should I do?

I tried reading documentation hoping there is some methods for printing unicodes, but there was nothing.
I checked encoding type, but it supported unicode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.